# How does sites like mint.com and sigfig.com (etc.) secure credential information

Tags: security

I'm looking for detailed insight into how does sites like mint.com and sigfig.com (etc.) secure credential information.  Millions of people trust not just their login information to the primary site, but also their FINANCIAL sites, and not just one but often MANY financial sites.

This is a question at the architecture level.  The sites obviously employ penetration testing, active monitoring etc.  And they must be doing strong encryption such as:

https://crackstation.net/hashing-security.htm

If a small business/web site wanted to be as secure as possible storing this information, how would they go about it?

Answer (score 0):

So you want to store user's passwords to external sites securely...

You can't use hashing here, because you need to know the plaintext value and send it to the external site to login.

Ideally you'd use something like OAUTH here instead, but not every site supports OAUTH.

Here's what I would do:

Encrypt the `external.com` credentials with a key derived from my password for `you.com` (I need to be logged in to `you.com` for you to grab data from `external.com`)

1. I create an account with `you.com` with a username and password and login
2. You hash my `you.com` password and store in the db
3. Each time I login, you generate a key derived from my plaintext password, which you keep in server-side session while I'm logged in
4. I add credentials for `external.com`
5. You encrypt these credentials with my `you.com` key and store in the db
6. You decrypt my `external.com` credentials with my `you.com` key and then login to `external.com` on my behalf

An even better approach would be to add a second server that only stores the external credentials and connects to the external sites and returns authentication details (like a session cookie).